# Stop PHP5 Web Server

Tags: php

The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) specify that `php -S <port>` starts a basic web server. Is there a way to stop this other than manually killing the process (`kill -9 PID`) ?

Comment: When you run the command, it prints "Press Ctrl-C to quit".

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+C will do the job. This you also can find in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no other way if daemon is detached from terminal. Linux start/stop scripts do same: they kill processes.

When you run daemon it saves info about process into `/var/run/your_daemon_name.pid` file. Start/stop script knows that `your_daemon` saves its PID (Process ID) into `your_daemon_name.pid` file. So it do someting like:

```
kill `cat /var/run/your_daemon_name.pid`
```